# spring batch log to different log file depending on batch id?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, spring-batch

I need to log messages to different log files which should be created at run time depending on the job parameter I am passing to while launching the job. e.g  batch_id=2014-07-01 etc.

I came across https://github.com/dsyer/log4j-utils and with the help of the test case, https://github.com/dsyer/log4j-utils/blob/master/src/test/resources/file-dispatcher.xml tried to configure in my spring batch admin project. Below is the configuration

```
<appender name="LOGGER" class="org.springframework.util.log4j.DispatcherAppender">
    <param name="propertyName" value="file" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="/var/log/st/batch.log.%x" />
    </layout>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/var/log/st/default.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p: %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <priority value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="LOGGER" />
</root
```

and in my class I am using

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.NDC;

public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void run(final String command, final long timeout) throws Exception {

        NDC.push("2014-07-01");

        logger.info("Running " + command);


    }
}
```

I am using this class to run commands through spring batch itemWriter in spring batch job.

It is not working, no log files are created and if we create manually and give full permissions still nothing is logged to log files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently in the process of implementing what you've stated, but with a different approach.
I've defined a JobLoggerGenerator class that creates an appender for each class it's called like so :

```
public static Appender getJobAppender(Class<?> class_) {

    PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout(
        logProperties.getProperty("log4j.appender.LogFile.layout.ConversionPattern"));

    FileAppender appender = null;
    try {
        // vérifier l'existance du paramétre
        if (UtilBatch.chaineVide(cheminExecutionJob)) {
            throw new IOException("Le chemin de depôt des fichiers est vide");
        }

        // vérifier et créer le dossier des traces
        String cheminDepotFichTraces = UtilBatch.verifierEtCreerChemin(cheminExecutionJob, "log");

        // ajouter le fichier des traces pour ce job
        appender = new FileAppender(layout,
            UtilBatch.creerLien(cheminDepotFichTraces, jobExecutionId + "_log.log"), true);
        appender.setEncoding(logProperties.getProperty("log4j.appender.LogFile.Encoding"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger mainLog = Logger.getLogger(class_);
        mainLog.error(jobExecutionId, e);
    }

    return appender;
}
```

Then, in my Service class for example I'll have a Logger object declared, which I'll modify like so :

```
log.addAppender(JobLoggerGenerator.getJobAppender(TestsServiceImpl.class));
```

Not the subtle approach is to initialize the JobExecutionId at the right time.
In Spring-batchs' case, the @BeforeStep is called AFTER the @Service classes are initialized, so an init method with @PostConstruct will not work here.

What I'm having to do instead, is to further modify the @BeforeStep method to 1) initialize de JobExecutionId, and 2) to call every service or dao class in which I need to log something, to add an appender to the Logger object. (I need to execute the line above for every service basically)..

Does this help you ?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  In your code 
    NDC.clear(); 
is missing. 
This could be a reason the file is not getting generated.